# spsComps gallery only enlarges once

Tags: r, shiny

I got an app that opens up a `modalDialog` with an image inside a `spsComps::gallery`. However, the enlargement works only the first time the modal has been opened. How can this be fixed? Here is a minimal reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("modal", "Open modal")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$modal,
               {
                 showModal(modalDialog(
                   title = "test",
                   fluidRow(gallery(
                     texts = "Click to enlarge", hrefs = "", image_frame_size = 6, 
                     images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/31/22/08/lion-3576045__340.jpg",
                     enlarge = TRUE, title = "When you close this modal, the enlargement does not work again",
                     enlarge_method = "modal"
                   )),
                   footer = modalButton("Cerrar"),
                   easyClose = TRUE,
                   size = "xl"))
               })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The first time the modal is opened, you can enlarge the image by clicking it. It looks like this:

[image]

However, when you ***close and then reopen the modal***, that enlargement feature is missing.

Comment: Can you please post pictures of what you get? I think I get exact same picture second time

Comment: It's not about the picture! It's about the enlargement feature; it does not work the second time around... I edited it to make it a little more clear.

Comment: I'm sorry I get exact same thing both times, I'm not sure if it's always or never OK . If you post the 2 different screenshots of your modal I probably will understand what you expect

Comment: I edited the question to give more detail on the problem

Comment: OK Thanks. Now I understand and reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary fix would be this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(spsComps)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("modal", "Open modal"),
    singleton(
        div(id = "sps-gallery-modal", class = "gallery-modal", 
            style="display: none;",
            onclick = "galModalClose()", tags$span(class = "gallery-modal-close", "X"), 
            tags$img(id = "sps-gallery-modal-content", 
            class = "gallery-modal-content"), 
            div(class = "gallery-caption")
   ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    observeEvent(input$modal,
                 {
                     showModal(modalDialog(
                         title = "test",
                         fluidRow(gallery(
                             texts = "", hrefs = "", image_frame_size = 6, 
                             images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/31/22/08/lion-3576045__340.jpg",
                             enlarge = TRUE, title = "When you close this modal, the enlargement does not work again",
                             enlarge_method = "modal"
                         )),
                         footer = modalButton("Cerrar"),
                         easyClose = TRUE,
                         size = "xl"))
                 })
    
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The reason is I have this `singleton(...` in the gallery creation function. There is only one enlarge img container needed to be created no matter how many galleries you have (It's not practical to enlarge two pictures at the same time). So enlarged images from different galleries are displayed inside the same enlarge container. This saves computer resources, and `singleton` in Shiny is the function to prevent duplication. Even if you may call `gallery` many times, if the content inside `singleton` is sent to the DOM tree only once, it will not append it again.

The problem is when `showModal` is closed, Shiny deletes everything inside the modal, including the gallery `singleton` content. Meanwhile, I think the `singleton` content validation stays at R level. It does not actually go search the DOM tree if this content exists or not. So Shiny thinks `singleton` content is there, and therefore refused to send it to DOM when the second time you call `showModal`.

The fix above append `singleton` content to `fluidPage` container instead of Shiny modal container, so when modal is closed, it cannot delete the content.

This is a universal problem in Shiny when you have `singleton` and `modalDialog`. There is nothing I can do to fix Shiny, but I may think of a more user-friendly way in the next `spsComps` version to address it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete answer, and thanks for your collaboration on this wonderful package!